# Updating the fallback handler

Tags: gnosis-safe

I set up my gnosis safe a while ago and it seems like I have an unofficial fallback handler, I want to update the fallback handler with the transaction builder, but ofc you don't get the additional info WHAT you have to insert/type in.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the address of your safe in the transaction builder (where prompted `Enter address or ENS name`), and choose `setFallbackHandler` in the dropdown menu (`Contract method selector`), with the address of the new fallback handler you want to set as `handler (address)`.

Hope it helps; Best, Louis